# I'm looking for how to get a similar picker for my application like currency converter for Android. Something like this:

Tags: android, android-layout

Image link:
[image]

In this both are scrollable, the one below the bar gets selected. As we enter value "588" US Dollar it will convert it in to British Pounds or which one is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a 2 ListViews side-by-side with BaseAdapters for each one and a pair of ImageViews to handle those selected items.

The shadow effect is done with a Gradient background. In OnItemClick() you'll handle selected items, putting ImageViews to View.Visible with setVisibility() method to show that arrow-on-arrow effect.

In short, read Android documentation for ListView, BaseAdapter, Gradients and ImageView.

Your layout would look like this:

LinearLayout (orientation horizontal) --- ListView--LinearLayout(separator)--ListView.